# Streaming data over WebSocket

Tags: javascript, websocket, streaming

I have the following setup: a Javascript client establish a WebSocket and send big loads of data over it. The data are presented as a string that can be several hundred Mo big. At the moment I cut the string in chunck of 16ko(totally arbitrary size) and send the chunk one after one :

```
chunk_size = 16384;
step = Math.floor(content.length/chunk_size);
for(i=0; i<step; i++){
  ws.send(content.substring(chunk_size*i, chunk_size*(i+1)));
}
```

My question concerns the Best Practice for that. Is this the correct  way to stream data, how are the streaming library usually implemented ?

or should I just send the all data load at once and let the WebSocket handle the streaming ?

Comment: What exactly are you streaming this data for?

Comment: Is this binary data, or strings?  JSON by chance?  I would use BinaryJS to set up the streams and let it worry about any chunking or compression of JSON for me.

Comment: thanks for your quick answer.@royhowie this is file transfer encoded as hex
@Brad it is string (hexa), I didn't make it clear in my question but the purpose is not to know what library works best but to understand how it is done

Comment: Don't use hex for binary data!  That's a huge overhead.  Web sockets support binary transfer directly.

Comment: @Brad hm, interresting remark. The data is presented as hexa by current app, but i could change that to get the binary directly, that would save some bytes.
That still leaves the question whats the best practice to split down chunk of data

Comment: @WKx lol yes, Javascript doesn't work with bytes so it has to convert it to hex in order to make sense out of it. I assume you meant Mb not Mo. i would cut the file into 2048 byte fragments. It really depends on your server configuration.