# Streaming data over WebSocket from JS client to Go server

Tags: javascript, go, websocket, streaming

## Background

I intend to stream `100x MB` or `GB` of data to a WebSocket server by JS clients. Like this post:

[Streaming data over WebSocket](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29000647/3405291)

But my server is in Go rather than JS. I mean there is a Go WebSocket server implemented by https://github.com/gorilla/websocket

One option suggested is to use BinaryJS:

[Streaming data over WebSocket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29000647/streaming-data-over-websocket#comment46249091_29000647)

## Problem

BinaryJS: both server and client are JS

##### Server

```
var BinaryServer = require('../../').BinaryServer;

// Start Binary.js server
var server = BinaryServer({port: 9000});
```

https://github.com/binaryjs/binaryjs/blob/79f51d6431e32226ab16e1b17bf7048e9a7e8cd9/examples/helloworld/server.js#L5

##### Client

```
<script src="http://cdn.binaryjs.com/0/binary.js"></script>
  <script>
    // Connect to Binary.js server
    var client = new BinaryClient('ws://localhost:9000');
```

https://github.com/binaryjs/binaryjs/blob/79f51d6431e32226ab16e1b17bf7048e9a7e8cd9/examples/helloworld/index.html#L6

## Question

Is it possible to use BinaryJS along with a Go server? Is any equivalent Go package?

Comment: Haven't used BinaryJS, so I'm not leaving an answer, but check out this tutorial, I found it useful for WebSockets in Golang: https://scotch.io/bar-talk/build-a-realtime-chat-server-with-go-and-websockets

Comment: @Aaron I'm going to study it =) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For data of `Float32Array` type above `200 MB` in size to be sent from JS to a Go WebSocket server, there is no need for streaming at all, tests show.

Just make sure `ws.binaryType = 'arraybuffer';` is used before `ws.send(positions);`.

```
                    var positions = attrPos.array;

                    function connect() {
                        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                            var ws = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8081/echo');
                            ws.onopen = function() {
                                resolve(ws);
                            };
                            ws.onerror = function(err) {
                                reject(err);
                            };
                            ws.onclose = function(evt) {
                                console.log("CLOSE SOCKET", new Date().toLocaleString());
                            };
                            ws.onmessage = function(evt) {
                                console.log("RESPONSE SOCKET: " + "RECEIVED" /* evt.data */, new Date().toLocaleString());
                            };
                        });
                    }
                    connect().then(function(ws) {
                        // onopen
                        console.log("OPENED SOCKET", new Date().toLocaleString());
                        console.log("SEND: START", new Date().toLocaleString());
                        ws.binaryType = 'arraybuffer'; // ** Critical statement
                        ws.send(positions);
                        ws.close();
                    }).catch(function(err) {
                        // onerror
                        console.log("ERROR: " + evt.data, new Date().toLocaleString());
                    });
```